# Confusion over storing a type in a temp variable in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a LINQ query which has a sort of subquery. It looks like this:

```
        var x = from p in pc
                let Cntrs = p.GetCounters().Where(args => args.CounterName == CounterName)
                select Cntrs;
```

Cntrs is a PerformanceCounter object. However, the intellisense returns it as a collection with collection methods.

I don't see the properties such as NextValue, etc (which is what I want).

What am I missing? Also, and I know this must have been asked before, what's the difference between the let and into keywords?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the `Where` method is returning more than one instance, in other words you have more than one counter whose name equals the value of your `CounterName` variable.

If you don't care which one you get you can use the `FirstOrDefault` extension method to retrieve the first item from the sequence that is being returned from the `Where` like this:

```
var x = from p in pc
        let Cntrs = p.GetCounters()
                     .Where(args => args.CounterName == CounterName)
                     .FirstOrDefault()
        select Cntrs;
```

Comment: Actually the Where() returns IENumerable. I used Take() to get 1 counter but that didn't work.

Comment: var x = from p in pc
                    let Cntrs = p.GetCounters().Where(args => args.CounterName == CounterName).Take(1)
                    select Cntrs.ElementAt(1);

That works, but if I take 1 (as above) then I don't want to be using ElementAt, when there is only one item.

Comment: Ah yes, first or default is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the var keyword, and the mystery will be resolved.

x is an `IEnumerable<PerformanceCounter>`

---

> Also, and I know this must have been
>   asked before, what's the difference
>   between the let and into keywords?

The keyword `let` introduces a new query variable into scope.

```
from c in Customer
let firstOrder = c.Orders.First()
select new {c, firstOrder}
```

The keyword `into` introduces a new query variable into scope and removes all previous query variables from scope.

```
from c in Customer
select new {c.Name, c.Orders} into smallerCustomer
select smallerCustomer.Name
```

c is not in scope in that last select clause.

```
from c in Customer
group c by c.Name[0] into g
select g.First()
```